Warp Reduce primitives to threads sharing same value
I'm facing the problem of reducing values to threads in warps that shares the same variable's content.
More specifically, in order to avoid atomic add operation on the an array i'm evaluating intermediate results for each thread, and then at the end I want to add their contibution to a single (leader) thread, responsible to write on memory. I took inspiration from the CUDA blog about the warp primitives.
I ended up having this, but obtaining incorrect results:
    __device__ void warp_aggregate_add(double *g, size_t offset, unsigned id, double dx, double dy, double dz) {
    unsigned mask = __match_any_sync(0xffffffff, id);

    double sum_dx = 0.;
    double sum_dy = 0.;
    double sum_dz = 0.;

    int leader = __ffs(mask) - 1;

    // Calculate the shuffle distance for the current thread
    int shuffle_distance = threadIdx.x - leader;
    sum_dx += __shfl_down_sync(0xffffffff, dx, shuffle_distance);
    sum_dy += __shfl_down_sync(0xffffffff, dy, shuffle_distance);
    sum_dz += __shfl_down_sync(0xffffffff, dz, shuffle_distance);

    __syncwarp();
    // Accumulate the shuffled values
    // leader only writes to memory
    if (threadIdx.x == leader && id != 0xFFFFFFFF) {
        g[offset + (id * 3)]     += sum_dx;
        g[offset + (id * 3) + 1] += sum_dy;
        g[offset + (id * 3) + 2] += sum_dz;
    }
}

where 0xFFFFFFFF is set for id of padded elements, that must not contribute to the sum.
I have 32 threads per block so we don't have to worry about using lane indexes.
I'm wondering if there is a well tested procedure to share the values to threads having the same id value.

You want to add all threads that have the same id?

Yes, in order to avoid atomic operations due to the same index of the g array. @Johan

Are you sure that using only 32 threads per block is a good idea in terms of performance in your use-case? The reduced occupancy due to limited blocks per SM and the reduced efficiency of memory accesses with such small blocks are the reason that 128 (8B global access) or 256 (4B global access) are recommended in the best practices guide.

If you want to add threads that have the same ID, you can do that like so:
__device__ float add_same_id(int id, /*float*/ int value) {
    const auto same_id_mask = __match_any_sync(-1u, id);
    //Needs ampere (sm_80) or newer
    //Oops, according to the programming guide
    //reduce_add_sync does not support float/double, only
    //signed/unsigned int.
    const auto sum = __reduce_add_sync(same_id_mask, value);
    return sum;
}

You can extend this for multiple sum values as needed, but note that this method is very slow, because both the match_any_sync and the reduce_add run slow if the mask is not -1u.
This will run very slow.
A faster way is using a leader and atomics, atomics are very fast on shared mem. Atomics on shared memory are really blazingly fast, I suggest you let go of your assumptions and give them a try.

__device__ uint32_t lanemask_lt() {
    uint32_t result;
    asm ("mov.u32 %0, %%lanemask_lt;" : "=r"(result));
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
__device__ float add_same_id(int& id, T value) {
    __shared__ T sum[32];
    __shared__ int ids[32];
    const auto laneid = threadIdx.x % 32;
    sum[laneid] = T(0);
    ids[laneid] = 0;
    const auto same_id_mask = __match_any_sync(-1u, id);
    const auto Leader = __ffs(same_id_mask) - 1;
    const auto LeaderMask = __ballot_sync(-1u, Leader == laneid);
    const auto LanesBefore = __popc(isLeaderMask & lanemask_lt());
    const auto Dest = __shfl_sync(-1u, LanesBefore, Leader);
    atomicAdd(&sum[Dest], value);
    atomicOr(&ids[Dest], id);
    __syncthreads(); //or __syncwarp(); if only 32 threads in block
    return sum[laneid];
    id = ids[laneid];    
}

One big disadvantage of the shared atomic add is that it the add will happen in indeterminate order, unlike the shfl reduction. Because adding floats/doubles is not associative, this will make your algorithm unstable.
Of course a shfl reduction has the same non associative error, it is just consistent in its error.
The fix to this is to use Kahan summation, this will reduce association error.

Atomics on shared memory take only a few cycles and are certainly not slower than global. You're not timing it right.

I've read that I'm not the only one facing this:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/atomicadd-in-shared-memory-is-measured-slower-than-in-global-memory-timing-shared-memory-atomic-o/25858
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/shared-memory-atomicadd-is-slower-than-that-of-using-global-memory/180272

you're compare a write+read from shared memory to a fire-and-forget write to global memory. Just a round-trip to L2 takes 200 cycles.  And the __match_any_sync by itself takes 500 cycles with 32 different ids. So 90 cycles as mentioned in the link is not very slow at all. If you don't make an apples to apples compare you can easily have the compiler replace your atomicAdd with a __reduce_add_sync underneigh which never touches main memory at all, except for the final outgoing write.

@ctrlaltdel Also note that the first forum post is quite old so the GPU might not have had hardware support for shared memory atomics (using locks instead).
